# Why can't I use the rule of complement in this case?

Tags: probability

I've been thinking about this question:

> On any given day, there is a $10\%$ chance that the bus you take will be delayed.
>
> What is the probability that the bus will be delayed two or more times between Monday and Friday?

Why can't I use the complement rule:

$$
1-\left(P(\text{Exactly delayed $0$ time})+ P(\text{Exactly delayed $1$ time})\right)
$$

So I use binomial formula:
$$
1-\left(\binom 50 \left((0.1)^0\right)\left((0.9)^5\right) 
      + \binom 51 \left((0.1)^1\right)\left((0.9)^4\right)\right)
$$

Comment: Why should that be wrong?

Comment: the answer I got from doing this way is different from the answer key :/

Comment: Seems like a correct approach and the right calculations to me. Are you certain you performed the calculations correctly? Are you certain that the answer key isn't wrong? Are you certain that you're checking the answer you think you're checking in the answer key, and not the one for next problem or something?

Comment: guys I'm so sorry, I did the wrong calculation on my calculator. XD

Comment: Happens to the best...